# Converting a Java Map object to a Properties object

Tags: java, dictionary, properties

Is anyone able to provide me with a better way than the below for converting a Java Map object to a Properties object?

```
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("key", "value");

    Properties properties = new Properties();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        properties.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this is a question better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use `Properties::putAll(Map<String,String>)` method:

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
map.put("key", "value");

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.putAll(map);
```

Comment: From the javadocs: Their use is strongly discouraged as they allow the caller to insert entries whose keys or values are not Strings.
In addition if the map happens to have keys that have null values then this will lead to a NPE.

Answer (score 11):

you also can use apache `commons-collection4`

`org.apache.commons.collections4.MapUtils#toProperties(Map<K, V>)`

example:

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

map.put("name", "feilong");
map.put("age", "18");
map.put("country", "china");

Properties properties = org.apache.commons.collections4.MapUtils.toProperties(map);
```

see javadoc

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MapUtils.html#toProperties(java.util.Map)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Commons Configuration:

```
Properties props = ConfigurationConverter.getProperties(new MapConfiguration(map));
```

http://commons.apache.org/configuration

Comment: @Reg Just use the version 2.7?

Comment: Same issues: Please see
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-configuration2/2.7

Comment: @Reg This is misleading, the vulnerabilities only affect optional or test dependencies of Commons Configuration. These dependencies are not pulled automatically into your project when you depend on Commons Configuration. For example, Commons Configuration can be used with Spring Framework, but it won't pull Spring for you, you have to declare the dependency with the right version yourself.

Comment: Hahahaha - I was wondering why you are so tied to this, I see you are a contributor to the project! (Well done and thank you) I deleted my first comment, but I do feel this is important information to take into account for any user.
In short for anyone reading this, check your version and make sure you do not expose any vulnerabilities :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [`MapAsProperties`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.cactoos/cactoos/0.10/org/cactoos/list/MapAsProperties.html) from [Cactoos](http://www.cactoos.org):

```
import org.cactoos.list.MapAsProperties;
import org.cactoos.list.MapEntry;
Properties pros = new MapAsProperties(
  new MapEntry<>("foo", "hello, world!")
  new MapEntry<>("bar", "bye, bye!")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the idea from [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-convert-properties-to-hashmap) but I modified to convert from a Map to Properties. This is needed if you may need to manipulate the inputs.

```
Map<String,String> input = System.getenv();
Properties output = input.entrySet().stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
        e -> String.valueOf(e.getKey()),
        e -> String.valueOf(e.getValue()),
        (prev, next) -> next, Properties::new
    )
);
```

Also if you want to filter values from the Map.

```
Map<String,String> input = System.getenv();
Properties output = input.entrySet()
.stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith("XYZ")).collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
        e -> String.valueOf(e.getKey()),
        e -> String.valueOf(e.getValue()),
        (prev, next) -> next, Properties::new
    )
);
```